# How can I split this string in c# and getthe first and last lat and long?

Tags: c#, split

in c# I get the following string:

```
[{"place_id":"92911594","licence":"Data \u00a9 OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL
1.0. http:\/\/www.openstreetmap.org\/copyright","osm_type":"way","osm_id":"12174
8552","boundingbox":["-33.4480414","-33.4439319","-70.6448054","-70.6266944"],"l
at":"-33.4460658","lon":"-70.6359402","display_name":"Mar\u00edn, Santiago, Prov
incia de Santiago, XIII Regi\u00f3n Metropolitana de Santiago, 8331059, Chile","
class":"highway","type":"tertiary","importance":0.2,"address":{"road":"Mar\u00ed
n","city":"Santiago","county":"Provincia de Santiago","state":"XIII Regi\u00f3n
Metropolitana de Santiago","postcode":"8331059","country":"Chile","country_code"
:"cl"},
"svg":"M -70.626694400000005 33.444016900000001 L 
-70.626853100000005 33.443931900000003 
-70.628024600000003 33.444266200000001 
-70.629083399999999 33.444542800000001 
-70.629957200000007 33.444764300000003 
-70.630791099999996 33.444983999999998 
-70.630836099999996 33.4449915 
-70.631027500000002 33.445031299999997
-70.631102900000002 33.445044099999997 
-70.631955300000001 33.445186900000003
-70.632777300000001 33.445343999999999 
-70.632846900000004 33.445356799999999 
-70.6329025 33.445371799999997 
-70.633783199999996 33.445576199999998 
-70.63402120 0000007 33.445624299999999 
-70.635066499999994 33.4458354 
-70.635940199999993 33.4460658 
-70.637316900000002 33.446388900000002 
-70.638039300000003 33.446610700000001 
-70.638551500000005 33.446730799999997 
-70.639778699999994 33.447019400000002 
-70.640489099999996 33.4471962 
-70.641005800000002 33.4473074 
-70.642197100000004 33.447521299999998 
-70.642251900000005 33.447535500000001 
-70.643692900000005 33.4478121 
-70.644805399999996 33.448041400000001
"}]
```

i need to get and save in some variable each lat-long pair from svg. For example:

```
pair1 = "-70.626694400000005 33.444016900000001"
pair2 = "-70.626853100000005 33.443931900000003"
pairx = ""
```

I'm tryng with split, but i cant get the pairs using regular expression.

Comment: This *string* is a json strong, use http://json2csharp.com/ to generate a class for your json, Parse your string to your object *(Deserialize)* and there you will get a `svg` string type property. Split it on space and get `First` and `Last`

Comment: Will you always get literal `"svg":"M` before your data?

Comment: You need? Great do it! And when you will have exact coding issue than you are welcome back!

Comment: you could also use the `using System.Web.Script.Serialization;` as well google some examples using `JavaScriptSerializer`

Answer (score 0):

Your string is a json string. So, you could create a class representing this json data

```
public class SomeClass{
   pubclis string place_id {get; set;}
   public string license 
   // other members
}
```

Then, you can use a JavascriptSerializer instance to convert the json data to an instance of SomeClass. After that, you can easily retrieve each instance properties.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I get this error: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: h. Path '', line 0, position 0. using this: var obj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("http://open.mapquestapi.com/nominatim/v1/search?&q=marin,+santiago&format=json&addressdetails=1&limit=1&polygon_svg=1&countrycodes=cl");

          var dict = obj.First.First.Children().Cast<JProperty>()
                      .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.Value);

          var dt = (string)dict["c"];
          var d = (double)dict["g"];
          Console.WriteLine(dt);

Answer (score 0):

There may be better ways, but:

```
public class Coord
{
    public double latitude;
    public double longitude;
}

var svg = "M -70.626694400000005 33.444016900000001 L -70.626853100000005 33.443931900000003 -70.628024600000003 33.444266200000001 -70.629083399999999 33.444542800000001 -70.629957200000007 33.444764300000003 -70.630791099999996 33.444983999999998 -70.630836099999996 33.4449915 -70.631027500000002 33.445031299999997 -70.631102900000002 33.445044099999997 -70.631955300000001 33.445186900000003 -70.632777300000001 33.445343999999999";

var formattedSvg = svg.Replace("M ", "").Replace("L ", "");

var values = formattedSvg.Split(' ').ToList().Select(v => Double.Parse(v)).ToArray();

var coords = new List<Coord>();

for (var index = 0; index < values.Length; index += 2)
{
    coords.Add(new Coord
    {
        latitude = values[index],
        longitude = values[index + 1]
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @paul, but How can i get svg value? Because this values are from the json string.

Comment: And how can i get the value from latitude and longitude and save it into some variable?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is JSON, the first thing you need to do is download [JSON.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json). Next, Create a class like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "svg")]
    public string Svg { get; set;}
}
```

Next, do this:

```
string svg = (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(myjsondata)).Svg;
```

This will give you the Svg string you need. Next you can do something like this:

```
    var pairs = new List<string>();

    string[] strings = svg.Split(' ');

    int ndx = 0;

    while (ndx < strings.Length - 1)
    {
        if (strings[ndx].StartsWith("M") || strings[ndx].StartsWith("L"))
        {
            ndx++;
            continue;
        }

        pairs.Add(strings[ndx] + " " + strings[ndx + 1]);
        ndx += 2;
    }

    foreach (string s in pairs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
```

Comment: I get the next error: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: h. Path '', line 0, position 0. What's wrong? Thanks!!

Comment: In this part:    string svg = (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(url)).Svg;